# Is it ok to put links in docstrings?

Tags: python, docstring

Say, for example, that I am writing a function based on a paper. Is it OK to put a link to the paper in the docstring? Or is this considered bad coding? I could imagine that being frowned upon by the Python community due to the fact that the link could break.

Comment: if it's a scientific paper, you could also add the DOI

Comment: Docstring are for providing information. What better way to provide information? Just remember the url might not always be live in the future. So provide more information instead of just links.

Comment: I always think that it is better to give more information than less, so why not?